# How can I repeat/retrigger onLongClick in Android

Tags: android, button, repeat, onlongclicklistener

Hi have a "scrub" or "scan" button on a music player that I'm writing. What I'd like my button to do is jump a number of milliseconds ahead in the tune every couple of second if the user holds the button for a long period of time.

How can I get multiple onLongClick() events to occur if I hold the button? At the moment I only get one and thats it. There must be a way to reset the timer so it happens again surely.. I hope?

Comment: Simply capture the KeyEvent ACTION_UP for stopping your scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that I cobbled together thats working well for me. I would have accepted the previous answers but they didn't take into account moving outside of the button's view. I hope the below code helps somebody else out in the same predicament. 90% of this code is not mine - so many thanks to the other stackoverflow posting that provided this.

EDIT: Actually, this is not perfect either - it doesn't animate button touches.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AutoRepeatButton extends Button
{

  private long     initialRepeatDelay                 = 500;
  private long     repeatIntervalInMilliseconds       = 1000;
  private boolean  mRepeatStarted = false;

  private Runnable repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable = new Runnable()
                                                      {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void run()
                                                        {
                                                          // Perform the present
                                                          // repetition of the
                                                          // click action
                                                          // provided by the
                                                          // user
                                                          // in
                                                          // setOnClickListener().
                                                          mRepeatStarted = true;

                                                          performLongClick();

                                                          // Schedule the next
                                                          // repetitions of the
                                                          // click action, using
                                                          // a faster repeat
                                                          // interval than the
                                                          // initial repeat
                                                          // delay interval.
                                                          postDelayed( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable, repeatIntervalInMilliseconds );
                                                        }
                                                      };

  private void commonConstructorCode()
  {
    mRepeatStarted = false;

    this.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener()
    {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event )
      {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
        {
          // Just to be sure that we removed all callbacks,
          // which should have occurred in the ACTION_UP
          removeCallbacks( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable );

          // Schedule the start of repetitions after a one half second delay.
          postDelayed( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable, initialRepeatDelay );
        }
        else
        if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
        {
          // Cancel any repetition in progress.
          removeCallbacks( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable );

          if( mRepeatStarted == false )
          {
            // PDS: I put this here..
            performClick();
          }

          mRepeatStarted = false;      
          return true;
        }
        else    
        if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
        {
          int[] l = new int[2];
          v.getLocationOnScreen( l );

          Rect rect = new Rect( l[0], l[1], l[0] + v.getWidth(), l[1] + v.getHeight() );

          if( ! rect.contains( v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(),
                               v.getTop()  + (int) event.getY())) 
          {
            // User moved outside bounds
            removeCallbacks( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable );

            mRepeatStarted = false;
          }
        }
        else
        if( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL )
        {
          removeCallbacks( repeatClickWhileButtonHeldRunnable );

          mRepeatStarted = false;
        }

        // Returning true here prevents performClick() from getting called
        // in the usual manner, which would be redundant, given that we are
        // already calling it above.
        return true;
      }
    } );
  }

  public AutoRepeatButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle )
  {
    super( context, attrs, defStyle );
    commonConstructorCode();
  }

  public AutoRepeatButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
  {
    super( context, attrs );
    commonConstructorCode();
  }

  public AutoRepeatButton( Context context )
  {
    super( context );
    commonConstructorCode();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start a Timer on `onLongClick()` that executes your jump action every second or two. Stop the Timer when you get the `ACTION_UP` keyEvent.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, you can listen for `onLongClick()` and then stop moving cursor on `ACTION_UP` event:

```
v.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
            if(isMoving)
            {
                isMoving = false;
                stopMovingCursor();
            }

        return false;
    }
});

v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        isMoving = true;
        startMovingCursor();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. A few days ago I implemented a subclass of Button but the problem with it was that you could touch down, move off the button and then touch up and the repetition would continue forever. I'll give it a try and let you know.